# password authentication failed for user postgres password retrieved from file

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I tried to register server by pgAdmin, but I got this error:

```
FATAL: password authentication failed for user postgres password retrieved from file
```

[image]

Comment: So, fix it.  Do you agree that the file exists, contains a password, and that the password is wrong?  If so, then do the obvious.

Comment: I found the .pg pass file and put the password in the field, but it not working and I have the same error again, even I deleted the .pg pass and it does not help @jjanes

Comment: After deleting the file, did you manually put the password into the password field of the GUI?

Comment: Yes, I put the password manually into the password field, but the authentication error still shows in GUI, finally, I create Postgres with docker-compose in a docker container and after that, the pgAdmin knows this! it's strange!!! @jjanes